# python file ouput filname.write(" "" ") is not writing to file ""

Tags: python, file, symbols

My Python script is not writing `""` by this code `filname.write(" "" ")` .

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Use single quotes: `filename.write(' "" ')`

Comment: What you actually have there is two strings, each with one space. Python automatically concatenates two adjacent strings when it interprets the code. So what you actually ended up with is one string with two spaces.

Answer (score 7):

You need to do:

```
filename.write(""" "" """)
```

or

```
filename.write(' "" ')
```